# need to calculate year,month and day for closing date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have a table called dates,

```
Opendate    |   Closedate   
------------+---------------
2015-07-09  |   2016-08-10
```

I am expecting the output like,

```
opendate    |   closedate   |   diff    
------------+---------------+----------------------
2015-07-09  |   2016-08-10  |   1year 1month 1day   
2015-07-09  |   2016-03-01  |   8 months 20 days
2015-07-09  |   2015-07-11  |   2 days
```

But when I run this query:

```
SELECT opendate, 
       closedate, 
       Datediff(year, opendate, closedate)  AS years, 
       Datediff(month, opendate, closedate) AS months, 
       Datediff(day, opendate, closedate)   AS days 
FROM   dates
```

It is giving me an output like,

```
opendate    |   closedate   | years | months |  days    
------------+---------------+-------+--------+---------
2015-07-09  |   2016-08-10  |   1   |   13   |  397
```

How can we calculate 1 year 1 month and 1 day

Comment: Whats should be the result when `closedate` is  `2016-03-01`

Comment: @Prdp it should be 8 months  and 20 days

Comment: So when close date is  `2015-07-11` result should be `2 days`

Comment: Added the abov scenarios in questions hope you dont mind

Comment: @prdp not at all, its actually good

Comment: just combine them like `cast(Datediff(year, opendate, closedate) as varchar)+' years'+....`

Comment: I suggest you to ignore `s` for `1 year(s)` ;).

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I trid what you suggested but it is giving me 1years 8month 248days. Which should not be the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Stacked CTE to find one by one the next year, month and date.

**Explanation**

Query Below first finds out the `DATEDIFF` Years of opendate and closedate and checks if the resulting date is greater than closedate. if it is, the actual year difference is `DATEDIFF` of Y -1. use this new date and fetch the `DATEDIFF` of months using the same logic and then get the difference in days.

[Online Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/509673)

**Query**

```
WITH D(Opendate,Closedate)AS
(
SELECT CAST('2015-07-09' AS DATE),CAST('2016-08-10' AS DATE)
UNION ALL 
SELECT CAST('2015-07-09' AS DATE),CAST('2016-03-01' AS DATE)
UNION ALL 
SELECT CAST('2015-07-09' AS DATE),CAST('2015-07-11' AS DATE)

),Y AS
(
SELECT Opendate,Closedate,
  CASE 
  WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,Opendate,Closedate),Opendate) > Closedate 
  THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,Opendate,Closedate) - 1 
  ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR,Opendate,Closedate)
  END Years
FROM D
), YDate as 
(
SELECT Opendate,Closedate,Years,DATEADD(YEAR,Years,Opendate) as Newopendate
FROM Y
),M AS
(
SELECT Opendate,Closedate,Years,Newopendate,
CASE WHEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,Newopendate,Closedate),Newopendate) > Closedate 
THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,Newopendate,Closedate) - 1 
ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH,Newopendate,Closedate) 
END Months
FROM YDate
) 
SELECT Opendate,Closedate,Years,Months,DATEDIFF(Day,DATEADD(MONTH,Months,Newopendate),Closedate) as days
FROM M
```

**Result**

```
Opendate    Closedate   Years   Months  days
09-07-2015 00:00    10-08-2016 00:00    1   1   1
09-07-2015 00:00    01-03-2016 00:00    0   7   21
09-07-2015 00:00    11-07-2015 00:00    0   0   2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT opendate, 
       closedate, 
       ( ( Datediff(year, opendate, closedate) +  'years' )+  
       (( Datediff(month, opendate, closedate) - 
             12 * Datediff(year, opendate, closedate)) + 'months') +
        ( Datediff(day, opendate, closedate) - 
         ( Datediff(year, opendate, closedate) * 365 - 
         (Datediff(month, opendate, closedate) * 12) )) + 'days'

FROM   dates
```

The logic is you concatenate the years and then deduct the no of months of a year. Similarly deduct for days as well

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'years' to data type int.

Answer (score 1):

Create one function as Below

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetYearMonthDays
    (
       @FromDate DATETIME
    )
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
    AS
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @date datetime, @tmpdate datetime, @years int, @months int, @days int
       SELECT @date =@FromDate

    SELECT @tmpdate = @date

    SELECT @years = DATEDIFF(yy, @tmpdate, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@date) > MONTH(GETDATE())) OR (MONTH(@date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    SELECT @tmpdate = DATEADD(yy, @years, @tmpdate)
    SELECT @months = DATEDIFF(m, @tmpdate, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    SELECT @tmpdate = DATEADD(m, @months, @tmpdate)
    SELECT @days = DATEDIFF(d, @tmpdate, GETDATE())

        RETURN  CONVERT(varchar(10), @years) +' Years   ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), @months)  + ' Month  ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @days) + ' Days'
    END
    GO
```

And use is as below

```
SELECT opendate, 
       closedate,dbo.GetYearMonthDays(closedate)
FROM   dates
```

This will give you what you wants.